# How can I customize an email-notification within a sharepoint 2010 workflow?

Tags: email, workflow, sharepoint-2010, customization

I've got a random workflow in my sharepoint application that allows employees to make a request for some holiday period! So some emails have to be send around.
I'd like tu customize this email-notifications in the following way:

- language (default is 'en', and I'd
  like to cange if possible)
- structure

thanks a lot!
george

Answer (score 0):

I still got no idea how you can customize an email-notification...perhaps you could look for it's tamplate and "customize" it there, but this would change it for all notificaitons...
so that's not a real solution!

anyway, I've found a quite good way to change the language. 
Well, email notifications always take the "default language" (which you can find in Site Actions/Site Settings/Site Administration/Language Settings) from the actual Site/SiteCollection/...
regarding to this problem you should check my answer to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599492/how-can-i-change-a-sites-default-language-after-creation-sharepoint-2010)

So, now you can change a Site's default language to a new one(of course only if you got the right [[Language ID](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff463779.aspx)]and the language pack(s) installed)...do some stuff like sending notification mails in favored language(s) (for example within a workflow like the one I've described above). 
When your work(act. the workflow's work) is done you can set back the Site's language to the original one and you're done!