# How can I change a site's default language after creation (sharepoint 2010)?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web, language-features

after creating a site you can go to:

Site Actions / Site Settings / Site Administration / Language Settings

and select some alternate language(s) if you've got some language pack(s) installed, but the default one is fix and you can't cange it anymore.
Is there a way or some settings.file where you can change the default language?

Answer (score 3):

OK, It's me again answering my own question(s)...

http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2008/04/29/changing-the-language-of-an-existing-sharepoint-site.aspx

It works so good this sql_way! 
After searching around for so long time I've finally found this soluion! done in a few seconds!

george